# How do I fix my media Query for HTML Email Template?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, html-email

I've tested this out on desktop and mobile by sending it to myself in an email (GMAIL & OUTLOOK), and I've noticed my media Query isn't working. Is there a better way to write this?

Bonus: I've also noticed the background image doesn't load on email.

[image: 1] Example of Email Text

[image: Inspector Mode Desktop]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>NASCAR Fan Email</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
            .photoText {
                left: 100px !important;
                font-size: 20px !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background: url('https://www.nascar.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2022/01/12/NASCAR_FanCouncil_DaytonaFanPhoto_1_LowerOpacity.png') no-repeat center center fixed;   -webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;">


    <table class="outer" style="margin: 0 auto; border:0; border-spacing: 0; align-items: center;
        font-family: Stainless-Bold; color: black; width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0;">
                <table style=" border-spacing: 0; width: 100%; border:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="fanCouncil" style="background-color: white; padding: 80px; text-align: center;  border-bottom: 15px solid; border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffd659 25%, #e4002b 25%, #e4002b 30%, #e4002b 60%, #007ac2 40%, #007ac2 75%) 5;">
                            <img class="fanHeader" src="https://www.nascar.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2022/01/07/NFC_Horiz_BlackRGB.png" alt="Fan Email" width="1200">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <table style="border:0;">
            <tr>
                <td class=" photoText " style="position: absolute; top: 400px; left: 200px;">
                    <p style="
                line-height: 2.2;
                max-width: 1200px;
                font-size: 40px;" class=" entryText ">Hello, <br> <br> We’d like to invite you to participate in a short survey about this past weekend’s races. This survey should take less than 5 minutes and will be open through Wednesday, August 25. We want to know what you think!
                    </p>

                    <a href="http://www.nascarfancouncil.com/c/al/5YVqVGmxA5g98218UalK-Bl/5bn1vdLmXO68WPcydpyM7J " class=" clickStart " style=" font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                text-decoration: none; color: black;">Click here to Start </a>
                    <p style="
                line-height: 2.2;
                max-width: 1200px;
                font-size: 40px;" class=" unableText "> If you are unable to click the link, please copy and past the full URL below into your browser:</p>

                    <a style=" font-size: 40px; color: black;" href="http://www.nascarfancouncil.com/c/al/5YVqVGmxA5g98218UalK-Bl/5bn1vdLmXO68WPcydpyM7J " class=" copyLink ">http://www.nascarfancouncil.com/c/al/5YVqVGmxA5g98218UalK-Bl/5bn1vdLmXO68WPcydpyM7J</a>

                    <p style="line-height: 2.2; max-width: 1200px; font-size: 40px;" class=" thankYou ">Thank you!<br>Official NASCAR Fan Council</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at the support for media queries here: https://www.litmus.com/blog/understanding-media-queries-in-html-email/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set background image with low opacity for HTML EMAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70685446/how-do-i-set-background-image-with-low-opacity-for-html-email)